# Create new Dataframes from a list of Dataframes in Pandas for Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several Dataframes in a list

```
df1 = {'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 'col2': [3, 4, 3, 8, 4, 5], 'col3': ['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat']}
df2 = {'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 'col2': [30, 40, 30, 80, 40, 50], 'col3': ['dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog']}
df3 = {'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 'col2': [31, 41, 31, 81, 41, 51], 'col3': ['whale', 'whale', 'whale', 'whale', 'whale', 'whale']}

dfList = [df1, df2, df3]
```

What I want is a list of dataframes where, where each new dataframe for each value in `col1`, with `col2` and `col3` as columns. The values of `col2` and `col3` should come from each dataframe `df1`, `df2`, `df3`.

```
     a
col2    col3
3       cat
30      dog
31      whale

     a
col2    col3
4       cat
40      dog
41      whale

     b
col2    col3
3       cat
30      dog
31      whale

     c
col2    col3
8       cat
80      dog
81      whale

....
```

I would also be interested if it is possible to have that in one dataframe, something like

```
    col2     col3
a   3        cat
    30       dog
    31       whale
a   4        cat
    40       dog
    41       whale
b   3        cat
    30       dog
    31       whale
c   8        cat
    80       dog
    81       whale
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat` and `groupby`:

```
df = (pd.concat(dfList)
        .assign(id=lambda d: d.groupby(['col1', 'col3']).cumcount())
      )

out = [d.drop(columns='id') for k,d in df.groupby(['col1', 'id'])]
```

output:

```
[  col1  col2   col3
 0    a     3    cat
 0    a    30    dog
 0    a    31  whale,
   col1  col2   col3
 1    a     4    cat
 1    a    40    dog
 1    a    41  whale,
   col1  col2   col3
 2    b     3    cat
 2    b    30    dog
 2    b    31  whale,
   col1  col2   col3
 3    c     8    cat
 3    c    80    dog
 3    c    81  whale,
   col1  col2   col3
 4    c     4    cat
 4    c    40    dog
 4    c    41  whale,
   col1  col2   col3
 5    d     5    cat
 5    d    50    dog
 5    d    51  whale]
```

Alternative:

```
df.set_index(['col1', 'id']).sort_index()
```

output:

```
         col2   col3
col1 id             
a    0      3    cat
     0     30    dog
     0     31  whale
     1      4    cat
     1     40    dog
     1     41  whale
b    0      3    cat
     0     30    dog
     0     31  whale
c    0      8    cat
     0     80    dog
     0     81  whale
     1      4    cat
     1     40    dog
     1     41  whale
d    0      5    cat
     0     50    dog
     0     51  whale
```